# Can't get AMPscript to write back to Salesforce from SMS

Tags: ampscript, sms

I successfully got AMPscript to write back to Salesforce in email/landing page using the updatesinglesalesforceobject function, but I can't recreate it in an SMS with MobileConnect. I finally got the code below to send the SMS text as indicated, but it doesn't write back to Salesforce and I can't figure out why it doesn't.

**What sends the SMS but doesn't write to Salesforce:**

```
%%[
VAR @mobile_number, @ContactID, @WorkOrderID, @time, @confirmtime, @Confirmation_Method__c, @Confirmation_Status__c, @Confirmation_Date__c
SET @mobile_number = [mobile_number]
SET @ContactID = [ContactID]
SET @WorkOrderID = Lookup("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME_HERE", "WorkOrderID","ContactPhone",@mobile_number)
SET @time = DateParse(Now(),1)
SET @confirmtime = Format(@time, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ")
SET @Confirmation_Method__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Method__c','Confirmed - Email')
SET @Confirmation_Status__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Status__c','Confirmed')
SET @Confirmation_Date__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Date__c',@confirmtime)
]%%
```

**What worked for Email:**

```
%%[
VAR @ContactID, @WorkOrderID, @time, @confirmtime, @Confirmation_Method__c, @Confirmation_Status__c, @Confirmation_Date__c
SET @ContactID = [ContactID]
SET @WorkOrderID = Lookup("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME_HERE", "WorkOrderID","ContactID",@ContactID)
SET @time = DateParse(Now(),1)
SET @confirmtime = Format(@time, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ")
SET @Confirmation_Method__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Method__c','Confirmed - Email')
SET @Confirmation_Status__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Status__c','Confirmed')
SET @Confirmation_Date__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Date__c',@confirmtime)
]%%
```

Comment: Are you able to confirm the value in @WorkOrderID?   I would assume your code that preforms a lookup by contactID will return a single value.  But, I'm not sure if you lookup by ContactPhone will return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
%%[
VAR @mobile_number, @WorkOrderID, @time, @confirmtime, @Confirmation_Method__c, @Confirmation_Status__c, @Confirmation_Date__c
SET @mobile_number = substring(Mobile_Number,2)
SET @WorkOrderID = Lookup("DATA_EXTENSION_NAME_HERE", "WorkOrderID","ContactPhone",@mobile_number)
SET @time = DateParse(Now(),1)
SET @confirmtime = Format(@time, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ")
SET @Confirmation_Method__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Method__c','Confirmed - Text')
SET @Confirmation_Status__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Status__c','Confirmed')
SET @Confirmation_Date__c = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Work_Order__c',@WorkOrderID,'Confirmation_Date__c',@confirmtime)
]%%
```