# UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(...) failing when trying to update a Date/Time in the CRM with Now()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, datetime

I have AMPScript within an SMS message, and I'm trying to update an Account record in the connected GovCloud (Salesforce CRM).  Here's my code:

```
UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account', AccountId, 'Appoinxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxent_Date_Time__c', Now())
```

AccountId is part of the Journey Entry Data - and this comes through just fine.  When I preview the SMS message, it renders the code and errors on this particular line.

[image]

Some things I've tried:

1. I've output Now() to the message just so I can see how it outputs.  Seems normal - just a normal date/time.
2. This field in the CRM is in fact a date/time data type.
3. I've tried messing around with Format(...) to no avail.

I've also attempted to run this journey, but as expected, I do not get the SMS message due to the error.  The journey's "Event Results" shows my record entering and being accepted into the journey.

Comment: Did you try formatting the datetime in UTC? Format(@time, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ")

That's the method that worked in a similar script for this question. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155916/cant-get-ampscript-to-write-back-to-salesforce-from-sms

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to convert to the correct format -
`SET @time = FormatDate(Now(), "iso")`

Or you can do it straight away inside the update function -
`UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account', AccountId, 'Appoinxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxent_Date_Time__c', FormatDate(Now(), "iso"))`